# Android Application(Client) and Server(C#.Net) Communication

Tags: android, android-development

I am confused which approach to choose - Poll (which waste battery), GCM or any other approach which suits best?

**Scenario is:** my client is **Android** and server is **C#.Net**. Server sends Invitation to client. Server can choose whom to send (Regionwise, Particular, To All). Client can accept or reject the invitation.which sends result back to server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Cloud Messaging will be definitely nicer to the users, because not only the application does not need to keep a foreground service (which implies status bar icon) running to keep a network connection open, it does not even need to be started at all. The GCM subsystem will start it itself.